# Unix or VIM command to format PHP code

Tags: php, formatting

I know that you can use the `indent` command to beautify `c` code.  I want to do the same thing with php but the command is giving errors (it is intended for c only I believe) is there a standard way to formatt php code with a command?  I would be open to either a unix command that comes with OS X or a VIM command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `vim` has been set up to recognize PHP, type `=G` at the top of your file and it will reindent your code to the end.

To expand on rkulla's comment, `=` is the indentation command, while `G` is the command to go to the end of the document and `gg` goes to the beginning.  If you want to indent the next 5 lines beginning from your current line, you can type `=5=` or `5==`.

Comment: in other words, 'gg=G'. Or visually select just the block you want to indent and type '='. When pasting code that you want to indent properly, ':set paste' first, then paste.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using VIM, erjiang's answer is the best method.  For reference for yourself or anyone reading this who does not use VIM, there is a PEAR module for beautifying PHP called 'PHP Beautifier'.

http://beautifyphp.sourceforge.net

See command line usage in the [documentation](http://beautifyphp.sourceforge.net/docs/).